# alterRoutes() is not triggered

Tags: 8

I am trying to alter the route for the login and registration pages. I followed [Altering existing routes and adding new routes based on dynamic ones](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones). I cleared the cache repeatedly, and re-enabled the module several times, but it looks like `alterRoutes()` is not triggered, even when I try to add a `kint()` debug or any code.

What I noticed is that `alterRoutes()` -> `kint()` is triggered when I use Drush to enable the module. In this case, I see `kint()` output in my terminal. However, `alterRoutes()` is not triggered when viewing the site.

This is the code I am using.

#### md_routes/src/Routing/RouteSubscriber.php

```
namespace Drupal\md_routes\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\RoutingEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;
/**
 * Listens to the dynamic route events.
 */
class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    kint($collection);
    // Change path '/user/login' to '/login'.
    if ($route = $collection->get('user.login')) {
      $route->setPath('/login');
    }
    if ($route = $collection->get('user.register')) {
      $route->setPath('/register');
    }
  }
}
```

#### md_routes/md_routes.services.yml

```
services:
  md_routes.route_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\md_routes\Routing\RouteSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

Comment: Did define md_routes.info.yml and . module files?

Comment: I did define the info.yml but not a .module file. Is this required? And what should the content be?

Comment: I tried adding an empty .module file. Re-enabled the module and cleared caches. But this is still not working.

Comment: Alter routes won't be triggered on every page request. It is built once until you rebuild the routes or clear the cache. So if the routes alteration are successful, meaning when the paths /login and /register are working as intended then all is good.

Comment: I have a custom page (using the page_manager module) with a panels view. In the region i render the login block. In the login block the link that sais 'Create new account'  using the user.register route still has the default path. This custom page does have /login as path and i also have on for register, does this conflict?

Comment: That's a different issue. Is `/login` and `/register` working as expected?

Comment: Don't assume `alterRoutes()` is not invoked just because you don't see the output of `kint()`. That is the wrong way to check a method is called from Drupal. As @awm said, the only way to be sure is verifying you get the login page for the path you define.

Comment: The new paths i assigned to the routes are not working. They still use the default `/user/login` and `/user/register` paths

Comment: Update: i did clear the drupal caches using the interface (`admin/config/development/performance`), it seems like drush is not clearing ALL caches. It does work now and i guess it was a caching issue. Thanks anyways!

Comment: It should happen only when you edit the code of an already installed module. Otherwise, when you install a new module, altering routes would have immediately effect.

Comment: I have noticed that `drush cr` is destroying the routes again. I have to use `drush cc` -> `3 router` after every cache rebuild or just use the interface to clear all caches

Answer (score -1):

I did clear the drupal caches using the interface (admin/config/development/performance), it seems like drush is not clearing ALL caches. It does work now and i guess it was a caching issue. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Drush *should* be clearing all caches. If it doesn't, then you might be using a different cache backend when using drush, e.g. there might be something in APCu or Redis/Memcache with a prefx that is different for web requests than with drush